# Manipulate AR camera size

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I need help regard Vuforia AR camera. I want the AR camera to be place inside the Main Camera so the AR camera can only detect Image targets within its range.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, what you are asking for is to change the "Cliping Planes" or the "Field of View" in the AR Camera.

The AR Camera that comes with Vuforia have the same values and you can change them to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vuforia 4.0 and above you'll notice that the Vuforia ARCamera comes as a compound element.

The hierarchy is as follows:

`AR Camera > Camera > Background Plane`

This simply indicates that the AR Camera is nothing but a normal Camera with an AR Wrapper on top of it using the name `AR Camera` with the QCAR scrtipts and Event Handlers.

Hence if you feel the need the change the `Clipping Planes` of the `AR Camera` you need to simply go to `Camera` which is the child of `AR Camera` and adjust the value of the `Clipping Planes` in the `Camera` component in the `Inspector Panel`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: im using vuforia-unity-android-ios-2-8-7.. i dont have that hierarchy (AR Camera > Camera > Background Plane)

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend you upgrade to Vuforia 4 and above because they did mention that licenses will not be valid for anything below Vuforia 4. And added to that you'll have all this functionality with Clipping Planes that you're looking for :) @aldrinloristo